# In ST4/C#, can you register a new renderer without a TemplateGroup?

Tags: c#, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

The only place the RegisterRenderer method appears is on TemplateGroup.  But I just have a single template, supplied via a string, not multiple templates on the file system.

Alternately, how can I use a TemplateGroup but supply the template(s) via a string?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured out how to do template groups from strings (the documentation is not good here, especially for the C# port). While not a solution to the actual problem, it is a workaround since I can register custom renderers with the group.

Essentially, I'm creating a template group for a single template, which seems silly, but whatever:

```
// Create the group (I'm specifying custom delimiters, but you don't have to)
var group = new TemplateGroup('$','$');

// Here's where we bind the renderers to a type. They will run on EVERY occurrence of this type, which means you have to handle situations in your renderer where no format string was specified -- that's still gonna get run through the renderer (very important with strings, for instance)
group.RegisterRenderer(typeof(DateTime), new DateRenderer());

//Here's where you "register" (define) a template. You have to give it a name, and (weirdly) specify all the attributes you're going to use
group.DefineTemplate("default", "[template code here]", new string[] { "nameOfAttribute" });
// You can define more templates here...

// Now, get the template back out using the name you used before
var template = group.GetInstanceOf("default");

// Add the data (correctly using the names specified when you defined the template above)
template.Add("nameOfAttribute", my attribute);

// Render
var result = template.Render();
```

Comment: This seems to work, but were you able to specify a format in your template? In the Java version you appear to be able to pass a string in `<e; format="f">`, but I get an exception when I try this: `[InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.]`

Comment: I guess I didn't try.  The Renderer just runs on every instance of that type.   I don't think I tried to pass in a format.

Comment: Never mind, there was a bug in my template where the double quotes `"` were being escaped into `&quot;`.  It looks like the format string is getting passed when the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The `RegisterRenderer()` Method is available via the `Group`-Property:

```
Dim tmpl As New Template(s, "$", "$")
tmpl.Group.RegisterRenderer(GetType(DateTime), New MyDateRenderer())
```